# Kafka automatically transforms the server ip into localhost

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am trying to get to know Kafka but I am having some problems. I installed Kafka on a Centos8 VPS, and everything works when I am connected to the VPS.

For the record, I opened the 9092 port for remote access.

The problem is that when I try to create a Message using Spring Boot, the Producer tries to connect to localhost instead of using the server ip address.

This is the configuration Bean :

```java
    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerStringFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();

        // the server name
        config.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "152.225.215.185:9092");
        // the key type
        config.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        // the value type
        config.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);

        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<String, String>(config);

    }
```

I use a simple method for producing Messages, with a hard coded topic name:

```java
// code
    private static final String TOPIC = "testTopic1";
//code

    @GetMapping("/publish/{message}")
    public String postString(@PathVariable String message) {

        kafkaStringTemplate.send(TOPIC, "This is a message sent to the " + TOPIC + " topic");
        return "Published:  " + message;

    }
```

When I launch a request I get the ip adress declared in the configuration bean :

```
2021-04-17 12:20:01.986  INFO 2520 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.k.clients.producer.ProducerConfig    : ProducerConfig values: 
    acks = 1
    batch.size = 16384
    bootstrap.servers = [152.255.215.185:9092]
```

But then Spring tries to connect to localhost, I suppose because
Kafka is set to automatically use localhost

```
2021-04-17 12:20:06.591  WARN 2520 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node 0 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
```

I suppose the answer is somewhere the Kafka configuration files.

Thank you for your answers.
For the record, I started learning Apache Kafka yesterday, so please excuse me for misusing technical terms.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution thanks to a video published by SelfTuts on Youtube:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jY5fzVCkABg

I had to modify the server.properties file :

```
 nano /usr/local/kafka/config/server.properties
```

Inside the file I added the server hosting Kafka Ip's address for the advertised.listeners and to the zookeeper.connect properties.

```
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://152.255.215.185:9092
zookeeper.connect=152.255.215.185:2181
```

Comment: Generally, you shouldn't run Zookeeper and the broker on the same host , but if they are, you can use localhost:2181 for it

Comment: I suppose that in my scenario the broker would come from Spring Boot. Unfortunately most of the (free, but  not only) tutorials use only localhost, so it is easy to get lost in a more real situation, where your work involves using remote resources. Thank you for your precision .

Comment: I'm referring only to the Kafka broker, nothing specific to Spring. And most tutorials assume you know a thing or two about distributed system networking

Comment: Having general knowledge about distributed system networking doesn't mean you will know how to configure any server for remote connexions